# Error trying to import python modules using jupyter package on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I'm using Pycharm with the jupyter package and sundently I can't import any module from pythons library (panda,numpy,...).

The error that I get is,

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I tried googling a solucion but nothing worked untill now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `pip install numpy`. pip comes with python. Use `pip --version` for checking installed pip version